# How to fix Error in file(con, "r") in cpcbp

Tags: r

I run to Phillips CPCA (`phillips.cpc`) with data simulated of examples of the package, but the output file is not generated and the function is not finished. May be is a code problem in `system(paste(progpath, "<", ansfn, "1> /dev/null 2>&1"))`?.

I use R version 3.6.1 in Ubuntu and the package was installed with `remotes::install_github("bbolker/cpcbp")`. This function is part of the package cpcbp. I have all dependencies suggest for cpcbp and some of the output files are generated but not the required file for continue the function. The work direction is the right one, i dont know what the problem. Also i tried to use the previous version of the package, installed manually, downloading the file cpcbp_0.3.2.1.tar.gz from [http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/R/src/contrib/](http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/%7Ebolker/R/src/contrib/) and occured the same

```
getwd() [1] "/home/duvan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/cpcbp/html"
setwd("/tmp/RtmptZpLKt")
library(cpcbp) 
set.seed(1001)
x = simdata(offset = 2, offset2 = 5)
# str(x) List of 2  $ data: num [1:400, 1:3] -7.621 -0.186 -0.374 9.342 2.746 ...  
# $ f   : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
phillips.cpc(x)
```

> `Error in file(con, "r") : Cannot open the connection`
>
> Also:
> `Warning messages: 1: In system(paste(progpath, "<", ansfn, "1> /dev/null 2>&1")) :   error in running command` `2: In file(con, "r") : Cannot open file '/tmp/RtmptZpLKt/cpcout3c414c66a273': No such file or directory`

I expect that the file `cpcout3c414c66a273` is generated

Comment: you've also sent this to me in private e-mail - please try not to cross-post in this way ... For the general readership, you'll need to tell them where they can find the `cpcbp` package, which is not on CRAN ...

Comment: Yes, the post was already edited

Comment: just a guess: what if you try a filename without any special characters (e.g. `Adem_s` rather than `Además`) ?

Comment: "Además" is part of the error message, it mean in Spanish "also", its no a filename. The filenames used in this case are generated by default. The post was already edited

Answer (score 0):

This problem was out the R. I reinstalled Rstudio and repaired broken packages in Ubuntu with:

`sudo apt --fix-missing update
 sudo apt install -f`

The problem was resolved